# Enviar mail de restablecer contraseña con emailjs

Tags: reactjs

Alguien sabe si es posible enviar un mail al usuario desde mi sitio web con *Emailjs*?

Necesito enviar mails en acciones específicas, por ejemplo: Al clickear en "*olvide mi contraseña*" se envíe un mail a ese usuario para poder completar el proceso o cuando clickea el botón de finalizar compra, enviarle un mail con el detalle de la misma, pero no sé cómo hacerlo actualmente.

Estuve averiguando en *emailjs* pero creo que el mail es sólo del usuario al sitio web y no al contrario.

Comment: Esa funcionalidad debe ser implementada desde el backend y no del frontend, así que no debería estar en la categoría React

Comment: si es posible, en la pagina de email.js tienes toda la documentacion, incluso te dan ya el script echo, tienes que crearte una cuenta, configurar tu servidor y configurar adecuadamente tu template para tu necesidad y listo, tienes si no me equivoco un max de 200 emails al mes o cada 2 meses no recuerdo bien.